# What is Error C2039 and what does it mean in this case?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

I cannot compile my code due to Errors like these:

```
Error C2039: 'difference_type' : is not a member of 'Player' c:\program files (x86)\
  microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 373 1 Football Simulator"
Error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of 'Player'  c:\program files (x86)\
  microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 371 1 Football Simulator"
```

And so on.

These messages offer nothing of value on how to fix the code or where the compiler is having trouble and left my with code that I now cannot compile.
There is one specific problem with my code, and I am getting a barrage of useless compiler errors and amidst one of those is a useful error that tells me where the actual mistake is

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jr2lmqwvfurpnok/Football%20Simulator.rar?dl=0
This is what I could gather of my code.
For reference, lines 371 of xutility read

```
// TEMPLATE CLASS iterator_traits
template<class _Iter>
    struct iterator_traits
    {   // get traits from iterator _Iter
    typedef typename _Iter::iterator_category iterator_category;
    typedef typename _Iter::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename _Iter::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef difference_type distance_type;  // retained
    typedef typename _Iter::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename _Iter::reference reference;
    };
```

This is my stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
```

And this is my Player.h Which is perfectly fine.

```
 #pragma once
#include "PlayerAttributes.h"
enum Position{
    GK,
    FB,
    CB,
    DM,
    CM,
    FW,
    MAX_POSITIONS
}; 

class Player
{
    PlayerAttributes Attributes;
    std::string m_sName;
    int m_nAge;
    Position m_ePosition;
    std::string e_sTeamName;

public:

    Player();
    Player(int nDesiredAttributeValues);
    //
    Player(std::string sName, int nAge, Position ePosition);

    Player(std::string sName, int nAge, Position ePosition, int nDesiredAttributeValues);
    ~Player();

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, Player &cPlayer);
};
```

EDIT:
And as pointed below, the actual error lies in file team.cpp

```
Team::Team(int nNumberOfPlayers, int nAttributeValue){

    acPlayer = new Player[nNumberOfPlayers];
    std::fill(acPlayer[0], acPlayer[nNumberOfPlayers-1], nAttributeValue);  // error
    nTeamSize = nNumberOfPlayers;
}
```

Nothing useful appeared on the error list and in the output, the 5th message stated:

**1>  team.cpp(13) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::fill(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled**

How am I supposed to identify the problem like this? My previous method was to check for the first error and go to the line stated, but that didn't work this time.

Thanks.

Comment: Please form an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it inline in your question.

Comment: I did my best, but unfortunately as the very problem is that I don't know where the problem originates, I cannot provide you exactly what that link asks for.

Comment: There should be a call stack with the error that leads back to your code.

Comment: How can I see this call stack?

Comment: But Johnny, producing an MCVE *tells you* where the problem originates. Part of the task of making it *minimal* is that you remove nonessential parts of your program until the error goes away. (Nonessential to producing the error, not to your program in general. Remember that once you identify the error, you'll go back and fix your original program.) When the error goes away, you've identified a key piece. Keep it and start removing other stuff. Repeat until you can't remove anything without the error disappearing. *Now* it's minimal, and you have additional clues about the cause.

Comment: I tried, and the error didn't go away, that is the very reason I am making this post, I must have spent about 5 hours trying to compile.  
I tried commenting out almost every portion of the code and it didn't make the problem go away, if that didn't work, trying to replicate the problem in a new project is going to be even harder.
Now I just tried making a new project using the old class to see if I could replicate it, it's just not possible to separate the classes without making them completely new classes, by the time the code compiles. If only the compiler could tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Another problem here is that, now I note that there are other things wrong with my code, like lack of namespace specifiers, for example if I call cout<<' ' without the std operator or using namespace. I DON'T GET ANY ERROR.
The same nonsense compiler errors are printed again.

Comment: @JohnnyBravo What is `Players`?  You have a stray `Players` in the code you posted.  Secondly, what is `PlayerAttributes`?

Comment: @JohnnyBravo I took the time to download your code and compiled it.  The error is right there in the error window, you just didn't have the patience to go to the line in your code that caused the problem.  Please compile your program, and take the time to go through that log -- you will see a reference to the line where you call `std::fill`.  Now that I gave you a clue, please update your question with this information.

Comment: That worked, Thank you
But how did you guys know how to check that error and ignore all the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my comment stated above, the error does show up in the Visual Studio output window, you just didn't see it (for some reason).

The error states this:

```
1>  team.cpp(13) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::fill<Player,int>(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
```

That error points to this in the `Team.cpp` file:

```
//Test Slow version
Team::Team(int nNumberOfPlayers, int nAttributeValue){

    acPlayer = new Player[nNumberOfPlayers];
    std::fill(acPlayer[0], acPlayer[nNumberOfPlayers-1], nAttributeValue);  // error
    nTeamSize = nNumberOfPlayers;
}
```

Now that everyone sees it, we now can tell you what the issue is.  The `std::fill` function requires iterators for the first two parameters, but you provided full blown objects, not iterators.

The fix is to do this:

```
    std::fill(acPlayer, acPlayer + nNumberOfPlayers, nAttributeValue);
```

A pointer has the same traits as an iterator that satisfies the conditions that `std::fill` requires.  The original problem was that the `std::fill` algorithm was applying `operator++` to the iterator, and since you passed an object that has no `++` defined, the error was emitted.

So contrary to your claims in the post, these are not "nonsense compiler errors".  The error makes perfect sense.

Comment: To be fair, errors like these are what C++ gets a bad rap for and will be much better when concepts are done. Something like *error: Player does not meet the requirements of ForwardIterator because <something about ++>* with the `std::fill` call being right after.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the description of error at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdwb3fd7.aspx

It looks like your code is using template. In template instantiation, somewhere, `difference_type` and `iterator_category` are expected from your class. It means either it is expected from your class object to provide these methods or you are passing the wrong type to the template function or object.

Check all the reference/usage of your class especially in template functions. That will help you to find the error.

Comment: My code is not using templates.

Comment: Your code might not be using template. But it might be passed to a function which can use template or STL or expects this function to present. You can generate preprocessed output and see the reference of above mentioned function.

Comment: @JohnnyBravo Your code is using templates.  It is using `std::fill` which is a templated function.